# A way to sort WordPress themes?

Tags: plugins, themes, directory

I want to write a plugin which can sort themes into categories.
For example
I have Categories

3 themes in Business as subfolder from /themes/business

7 themes in Nature /themes/nature

2 themein in private /themes/private

by default WordPress shows me all 12 themes in the backend.

I tried to change the theme root

```
add_filter("theme_root","tr");
function tr($J){
print_r($J);//if yo udo this you see the main theme folder
$J="/www/wp-content/new-themes"; //folder new-themes exists
return $J;
}
```

but in general this does not work.

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: You can just put the themes under each subfolders.
i.e. 
/theme/business/business-1-theme
/theme/business/business-2-theme
/theme/nature/nature-1-theme
/theme/nature/nature-2-theme.
etc....

Comment: Thank you solved this problem http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-folders/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the asker seems not search for an answer anymore.